# Denormalization of a table (Pivot?)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm facing with this problem, and I have no idea how to solve.

I m storing an organizational structure in 2 tables, organizations and relations; my goal is to build (possible on the fly, via stored proc or something similar) a **DENORMALIZED** table that report, **one row per organizational unit**, the path to the top of tree, with a fixed deepness.

I am actually able to do this using cursors and other stuff like this, but I am wondering if there is a faster way (cursors takes more than 4 minutes of processing ~4500 object codes)

The `organizations` table has four fields:

1. object code
2. object description
3. begin date of object
4. end date of object (31 dec 9999 if infinite)

The `relations` table has four fields:

1. object code
2. father code
3. begin date of relation
4. end date of relation (31 dec 9999 if infinite)

The resulting table should have the following fields:

1. obj code
2. obj description
3. root object code (lev 0)
4. root object descr (lev 0)
5. first ancestor code (lev 1)
6. first object descr (lev 1)
7. second object code (lev 2)
8. second object descr (lev 2)
9. and so on, till level 12 - FIXED

Now, I am able to get all records with the following SQL

```
DECLARE
    @datRif dateTime = convert(datetime, '20151231', 103),
    @codUo char(8) = '50043899',
    @withMe char(1) = ' ',
    @currentUo char(8) = '50043899'

DECLARE @path TABLE (
    leaf char(8),
    ancestor char(8),
    desAncestor varchar(50),
    deepLevel int
)

DECLARE cUOs cursor for
    SELECT objCode
        FROM organizations
    WHERE 
        objType = 'O' AND
        begDate <= @datRif AND
        endDate >= @datRif

OPEN cUOs

FETCH NEXT FROM cUOs 
INTO @currentUo

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN


    with n (codUo, deepLev) AS
    (SELECT r.objCode, 0
        FROM relations r 
        WHERE r.objCode = @currentUo and 
                r.begDate <= @datRif and r.endDate >= @datRif
     UNION ALL
     SELECT nplus1.fatherCode, n.deepLev + 1 
        FROM relations  nplus1, n
        WHERE n.codUo = nplus1.objCode   and 
                nplus1.begDate <= @datRif and nplus1.endDate >= @datRif
    )

    insert into @path
    select @currentUo as leaf, n.codUo, o.longText, n.deepLev
    from n left outer join organizations o on n.codUo = o.objCode
    WHERE (o.begDate <= @datRif and o.endDate >= @datRif) or 
        o.begDate = null
    order by n.deepLev DESC, o.longText

-- Get the next UO code.
FETCH NEXT FROM cUOs 
    INTO @currentUo;

END
CLOSE cUOs
DEALLOCATE cUOs

SELECT *
from @path
```

This code gave me the following set of data:

```
leaf        ancestor    desAncestor     deepLevel 
50000135    50032466    HOLDING         1
50000135    50000135    CEO             0 
50023726    50032466    HOLDING         2
50023726    50000135    CEO             1 
50023726    50023726    CEO_HR          0
50016541    50032466    HOLDING         3 
50016541    50000135    CEO             2
50016541    50023726    CEO_HR          1 
50016541    50016541    CEO_HR_ORG      0
50043899    50032466    HOLDING         4 
50043899    50000135    CEO             3
50043899    50023726    CEO_HR          2 
50043899    50016541    CEO_HR_ORG      1
50043899    50043899    CEO_HR_ORG_HRIS 0
```

What I really need is something like this:

```
object      object descr    root        root desc       uo1         uo1 desc        uo2         uo2 desc        uo3         uo3 desc        uo4         uo4 desc        
50043899    CEO_HR_ORG_HRIS 50032466    HOLDING         50000135    CEO             50023726    CEO_HR          50016541    CEO_HR_ORG      
50016541    CEO_HR_ORG      50032466    HOLDING         50000135    CEO             50023726    CEO_HR          
50023726    CEO_HR          50032466    HOLDING         50000135    CEO             
50000135    CEO             50032466    HOLDING
```

If someone would like to give a look, I add some scripts to generate the tables and data.
(the running DB is MS-SQL 2008 r2)

Thank you in advance

Paolo

```
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[organizations]    Script Date: 08/01/2016 17:44:27 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[organizations](
    [objCode] [nvarchar](8) NOT NULL,
    [begDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [endDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [longText] [nvarchar](40) NULL,
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[relations]    Script Date: 08/01/2016 17:46:28 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[relations](
    [fatherCode] [nvarchar](8) NOT NULL,
    [objCode] [nvarchar](8) NOT NULL,
    [begDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [endDate] [datetime] NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO


INSERT [dbo].[organizations] ([objCode], [begDate], [endDate], [longText]) VALUES (N'50000135', CAST(0x00008C8700000000 AS DateTime), CAST(0x000095CE00000000 AS DateTime) N'CEO')
INSERT [dbo].[organizations] ([objCode], [begDate], [endDate], [longText]) VALUES (N'50016541', CAST(0x000090F300000000 AS DateTime), CAST(0x0000919D00000000 AS DateTime), N'CEO_HR_ORG')
INSERT [dbo].[organizations] ([objCode], [begDate], [endDate], [longText]) VALUES (N'50016541', CAST(0x0000919E00000000 AS DateTime), CAST(0x0000936F00000000 AS DateTime), N'CEO_HR_ORG')
INSERT [dbo].[organizations] ([objCode], [begDate], [endDate], [longText]) VALUES (N'50016541', CAST(0x0000937000000000 AS DateTime), CAST(0x0000945600000000 AS DateTime), N'CEO_HR_ORG')
INSERT [dbo].[organizations] ([objCode], [begDate], [endDate], [longText]) VALUES (N'50023726', CAST(0x0000943E00000000 AS DateTime), CAST(0x0000945200000000 AS DateTime), N'CEO_HR')
INSERT [dbo].[organizations] ([objCode], [begDate], [endDate], [longText]) VALUES (N'50023726', CAST(0x0000945300000000 AS DateTime), CAST(0x0000945600000000 AS DateTime), N'CEO_HR')
INSERT [dbo].[organizations] ([objCode], [begDate], [endDate], [longText]) VALUES (N'50016541', CAST(0x0000945700000000 AS DateTime), CAST(0x0000945700000000 AS DateTime), N'CEO_HR_ORG')
INSERT [dbo].[organizations] ([objCode], [begDate], [endDate], [longText]) VALUES (N'50023726', CAST(0x0000945700000000 AS DateTime), CAST(0x0000946000000000 AS DateTime), N'CEO_HR')
INSERT [dbo].[organizations] ([objCode], [begDate], [endDate], [longText]) VALUES (N'50016541', CAST(0x0000945800000000 AS DateTime), CAST(0x0000946000000000 AS DateTime), N'CEO_HR_ORG')
INSERT [dbo].[organizations] ([objCode], [begDate], [endDate], [longText]) VALUES (N'50016541', CAST(0x0000946100000000 AS DateTime), CAST(0x0000974A00000000 AS DateTime), N'CEO_HR_ORG')
INSERT [dbo].[organizations] ([objCode], [begDate], [endDate], [longText]) VALUES (N'50023726', CAST(0x0000946100000000 AS DateTime), CAST(0x000097B300000000 AS DateTime), N'CEO_HR')
INSERT [dbo].[organizations] ([objCode], [begDate], [endDate], [longText]) VALUES (N'50000135', CAST(0x000095CF00000000 AS DateTime), CAST(0x00009A1500000000 AS DateTime), N'CEO')
INSERT [dbo].[organizations] ([objCode], [begDate], [endDate], [longText]) VALUES (N'50016541', CAST(0x0000974B00000000 AS DateTime), CAST(0x000097F000000000 AS DateTime), N'CEO_HR_ORG')
INSERT [dbo].[organizations] ([objCode], [begDate], [endDate], [longText]) VALUES (N'50032466', CAST(0x0000977700000000 AS DateTime), CAST(0x0000A0DC00000000 AS DateTime), N'HOLDING')
INSERT [dbo].[organizations] ([objCode], [begDate], [endDate], [longText]) VALUES (N'50023726', CAST(0x000097B400000000 AS DateTime), CAST(0x000098A800000000 AS DateTime), N'CEO_HR')
INSERT [dbo].[organizations] ([objCode], [begDate], [endDate], [longText]) VALUES (N'50016541', CAST(0x000097F100000000 AS DateTime), CAST(0x0000A14900000000 AS DateTime), N'CEO_HR_ORG')
INSERT [dbo].[organizations] ([objCode], [begDate], [endDate], [longText]) VALUES (N'50023726', CAST(0x000098A900000000 AS DateTime), CAST(0x002D247F00000000 AS DateTime), N'CEO_HR')
INSERT [dbo].[organizations] ([objCode], [begDate], [endDate], [longText]) VALUES (N'50000135', CAST(0x00009A1600000000 AS DateTime), CAST(0x00009CD200000000 AS DateTime), N'CEO')
INSERT [dbo].[organizations] ([objCode], [begDate], [endDate], [longText]) VALUES (N'50000135', CAST(0x00009CD300000000 AS DateTime), CAST(0x002D247F00000000 AS DateTime), N'CEO')
INSERT [dbo].[organizations] ([objCode], [begDate], [endDate], [longText]) VALUES (N'50043899', CAST(0x00009EC200000000 AS DateTime), CAST(0x0000A13800000000 AS DateTime), N'CEO_HR_ORG_HRIS')
INSERT [dbo].[organizations] ([objCode], [begDate], [endDate], [longText]) VALUES (N'50032466', CAST(0x0000A0DD00000000 AS DateTime), CAST(0x002D247F00000000 AS DateTime), N'HOLDING')
INSERT [dbo].[organizations] ([objCode], [begDate], [endDate], [longText]) VALUES (N'50043899', CAST(0x0000A13900000000 AS DateTime), CAST(0x0000A28600000000 AS DateTime), N'CEO_HR_ORG_HRIS')
INSERT [dbo].[organizations] ([objCode], [begDate], [endDate], [longText]) VALUES (N'50016541', CAST(0x0000A14A00000000 AS DateTime), CAST(0x002D247F00000000 AS DateTime), N'CEO_HR_ORG')
INSERT [dbo].[organizations] ([objCode], [begDate], [endDate], [longText]) VALUES (N'50043899', CAST(0x0000A28700000000 AS DateTime), CAST(0x0000A3A700000000 AS DateTime), N'CEO_HR_ORG_HRIS')
INSERT [dbo].[organizations] ([objCode], [begDate], [endDate], [longText]) VALUES (N'50043899', CAST(0x0000A3A800000000 AS DateTime), CAST(0x0000A3A800000000 AS DateTime), N'CEO_HR_ORG_HRIS')
INSERT [dbo].[organizations] ([objCode], [begDate], [endDate], [longText]) VALUES (N'50043899', CAST(0x0000A3A900000000 AS DateTime), CAST(0x0000A45600000000 AS DateTime), N'CEO_HR_ORG_HRIS')
INSERT [dbo].[organizations] ([objCode], [begDate], [endDate], [longText]) VALUES (N'50043899', CAST(0x0000A45700000000 AS DateTime), CAST(0x002D247F00000000 AS DateTime), N'CEO_HR_ORG_HRIS')
INSERT [dbo].[relations] ([fatherCode], [begDate], [endDate]) VALUES (N'50000135', N'50023726', CAST(0x0000943E00000000 AS DateTime), CAST(0x002D247F00000000 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[relations] ([fatherCode], [begDate], [endDate]) VALUES (N'50015420', N'50016541', CAST(0x000090F300000000 AS DateTime), CAST(0x0000945600000000 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[relations] ([fatherCode], [begDate], [endDate]) VALUES (N'50016541', N'50043899', CAST(0x0000A14A00000000 AS DateTime), CAST(0x002D247F00000000 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[relations] ([fatherCode], [begDate], [endDate]) VALUES (N'50023726', N'50016541', CAST(0x0000945700000000 AS DateTime), CAST(0x002D247F00000000 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[relations] ([fatherCode], [begDate], [endDate]) VALUES (N'50032466', N'50000135', CAST(0x0000A0DD00000000 AS DateTime), CAST(0x002D247F00000000 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[relations] ([fatherCode], [begDate], [endDate]) VALUES (N'50042187', N'50043899', CAST(0x00009EC200000000 AS DateTime), CAST(0x0000A14900000000 AS DateTime))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this.. I can't say that it would perform any better but it gets the result.

I used all at CTE first (hence the names) but you'd probably get better performance with temp tables so I used temp tables instead.

You still need to add level 6-12.

```
DECLARE @datRif dateTime = convert(datetime, '20151231', 103)

SELECT  COALESCE(r.objCode,o.objCode) objCode,
        longText,
        r.fatherCode
INTO    #baseCTE
FROM    dbo.organizations o
        LEFT JOIN dbo.relations r ON o.objCode = r.objCode
                                        AND @datRif BETWEEN r.begDate AND r.endDate
WHERE   @datRif BETWEEN o.begDate AND o.endDate

;WITH recursiveCte AS 
(
    SELECT  objCode,
            longText,
            fatherCode,
            objCode AS [Root],
            0 AS [Level]
    FROM    #baseCTE
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT  base.objCode,
            base.longText,
            base.fatherCode,
            [Root],
            [Level] + 1
    FROM    #baseCTE base
            JOIN recursiveCte c ON c.fatherCode = base.objCode

)
SELECT  *, 
        COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY [Root]) Cnt,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [Root] ORDER BY [Level] DESC) Rn
INTO    #groupedCte
FROM    recursiveCte 

SELECT  cte.longText,
        cte.[Root] objRoot,
        cte.objCode,
        [root].objCode AS [root],
        [root].longText AS [root desc],
        cte.Cnt, 
        cte.Level,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY cte.Cnt ORDER BY cte.Rn) [order]
INTO    #finalCte
FROM    #groupedCte cte
        JOIN (SELECT * FROM #groupedCte WHERE RN = 1) [root] ON [root].[Root] = cte.[Root]
WHERE   cte.Rn <> 1

SELECT  t.objRoot [object],
        t.longText [object descr],
        t.root,
        t.[root desc],
        uo1.objCode [uo1],
        uo1.longText [uo1 desc],
        uo2.objCode [uo2],
        uo2.longText [uo2 desc],
        uo3.objCode [uo3],
        uo3.longText [uo3 desc],
        uo4.objCode [uo4],
        uo4.longText [uo4 desc],
        uo5.objCode [uo5],
        uo5.longText [uo5 desc]
FROM    #finalCte t
        OUTER APPLY(SELECT * FROM #finalCte f WHERE f.Cnt = t.Cnt AND f.[order] = 1 AND f.Level <> 0) uo1
        OUTER APPLY(SELECT * FROM #finalCte f WHERE f.Cnt = t.Cnt AND f.[order] = 2 AND f.Level <> 0) uo2
        OUTER APPLY(SELECT * FROM #finalCte f WHERE f.Cnt = t.Cnt AND f.[order] = 3 AND f.Level <> 0) uo3
        OUTER APPLY(SELECT * FROM #finalCte f WHERE f.Cnt = t.Cnt AND f.[order] = 4 AND f.Level <> 0) uo4
        OUTER APPLY(SELECT * FROM #finalCte f WHERE f.Cnt = t.Cnt AND f.[order] = 5 AND f.Level <> 0) uo5
WHERE   t.Level = 0
ORDER BY t.Cnt DESC,
        t.Level
```